# I need 2 count values from single column to be in same row using Over () clause

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have the following Result from Select statement

```
UnitId     UnitType  GroupId
 1          1          1
 2          1          1
 3          1          2
 4          2          2
 5          2          2
 6          2          2
 7          2          2
```

I need the following result for each group Id

```
GroupId CountBasedOnUnitType1 CountBasedOnUnitType2
   1           2                      0
   2           1                      4
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM
(
  SELECT GroupId,
    UnitType
  FROM Table1
) x
Pivot
(
  Count(UnitType)
  For UnitType in ([1], [2])
) p
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/440bcf/3)**

*Output*

---

```
GroupId        1          2
   1           2          0
   2           1          4
```

Comment: Is there any other way without declaring column names? What happens if there are houndreds of Groups?

Comment: Dynamic usage can be seen here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15745042/efficiently-convert-rows-to-columns-in-sql-server

Answer (score 0):

Does in necessarily need to have `OVER`?

```
select 
  GroupID, 
  sum(case when UnitType = 1 then 1 else 0 end) CountBasedOnUnitType1, 
  sum(case when UnitType = 2 then 1 else 0 end) CountBasedOnUnitType2
from table
group by GroupID
```

Comment: I have achieved this usign OVER Clause as : SELECT  
 gu.GroupId
,Count(CASE gu.UnitType WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) OVER (PARTITION BY gu.GroupId) AS CountBasedOnUnitType1
,Count(CASE gu.UnitType WHEN 2 THEN 2 ELSE NULL END) OVER (PARTITION BY gu.GroupId) AS CountBasedOnUnitType2
FROM Group_Unit gu